# Image number of pictures and dpi

Tags: image, image-processing, resolution, screen-resolution

An image is broken down in picture elements (pixels) which means that when I check the attributes of an e.g. JPEG image stored on disk I can see e.g. `532 × 1051 pixels` which means the width is `532` the height is `1051`.
It also says in the attributes of the file that the color model is RGB which would mean 1 byte for each channel = 3 bytes to describe the color.
So I would assume that the actual size of the image is:
`532x1051x3= 1.67MB`
But what I see is that the actual file size reported is 45KB.
So does this mean that the `1.67MB` is the size of the image in memory?
Also I see as part of the meta data: `Image DPI: 96 pixels/inch`.
What exactly is this information used for?

Comment: The `dpi` is largely irrelevant until you print a file - at that point it just means the print will be 5.5" wide (532/96). The 45kB arises because JPEG compresses your image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: So the `96 pixes/inch` is not being used at all when we view the image in any program?

Comment: Some programs do use it. Some photography competitions insist on it. I have no idea why. Ultimately the number of pixels you have will determine what quality you have - it's no use having 360 dpi if you only have 2x2 pixels in your image. I'd rather have 8000x6000 pixels at 64 dpi.

Comment: The 1.67MB in memory is not strictly correct either, by the way. A program may choose to store the R, G and B pixels in a 2-byte `unsigned short` each, or a 4-byte `int32` each or an 8-byte `float64` each or some other way. Some programs store as RB565 which means 2 bytes in total for all three RGB components.

Comment: Image files not necessarily store pixel values (it depends on the extension). Some extensions store other kinds of information, based on which they can calculate an estimate of the original image. This leads to smaller file sizes althugh usually in worse quality. Try to convert a large, high quality png image to jpeg. When you zoom in you will see a lot of weird (obivusly wrong) image artifacts but it has only a portion of the size. As for the question; no it won't have the same size when you store it pixel by pixel in memory because that is the calculated estimate / restored value.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: The `532x1051` is the number of triplets then of RGB colors? And these colors can take X bytes to represent them? So how does a program decide how big it should display the image?

Comment: @user2986898: Then how does a program decide how big should the image be when opened?

Comment: Usually containers / extensions have a so called header (a section of the file at its beginning) containing meta information, such as size and extension (possibly date of creation, geo information etc.)

Comment: @user2986898: What do you mean by `size`? The size it should be displayed? And how can I see these meta info?

Comment: I mean the number of pixel in the (restored / estimated) image by `size`. Probably there are libraries that make it possible to read only the header info but I don't know any. If I would have to start somewhere I would try to use the utilities of the operating system. The Windows file explorer for example provides access to the metainfo (through the `properties` of the file). Powershell can be used to automatically gather these pieces of information. I'd guess there is similar possibilities for the Linux/Bash combo.

Comment: Use `jhead -v image.jpg` to see all the header information

Answer (score 1):

> But what I see is that the actual file size reported is 45KB

That's because JPEG images are compressed in multiple ways to save up space, sometimes up to a factor of ten so this is not unusual. You can just search for "jpeg compression" and read how it is done in detail if you're interested.

> Also I see as part of the meta data: Image DPI: 96 pixels/inch. What
>   exactly is this information used for?

Generally, as long as you are only interested in the image stored digitally you do not use it at all, because the image is not stored in inches. You could change the DPI and the image itself would not change, just the image header.

DPI only makes sense once you display/print the image. Then you could take it as a general recommendation on which resolution you should print this image. If you want to print a huge landscape with only 50 pixels per inch, it will not look good. If you however want to print a small logo with low DPI it might still look fine. So it really depends highly on the context of the image.

Comment: Then how does a program decide what size to show an image? Solely based on the pixels WxH?

Comment: Yes, generally you only rely on pixel dimensions when rendering something on a monitor. DPI only really makes sense when scanning (higher DPI = more pixels = higher resolution in resulting digital image) or printing an image.